# Can I steal neutral from fixture for 3-way switch device with no neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral, multiway-switch, smart-switch

my 3-way switch is wired this way, because i am unlucky:

[image: 3-way with no neutral in one switch]

so i have neutral in the line box, no neutral in the load box. i want to use a leviton smart switch that requires neutral in both boxes. if i were crafty enough, could i pigtail a new line off the neutral line in the **fixture** to run down to the load box? i am super green at this, so forgive me for asking a stupid question. there's also some information out there saying i can use one of the travelers as neutral, which i'll try first... i'm just playing 'worst case scenario'.

Comment: You are not unlucky this was the common way to wire a 3 way switch until recent code changes very few homes have neutrals at all the switches.

Comment: Wow, never thought I'd see that.  A web drawing that is correct.

Comment: What model of Leviton smartswitch do you want to use?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's a leviton decora digital w/ wifi. this model: https://www.leviton.com/en/products/dw6hd-1bz

Comment: How hard would it be to replace the wiring from the *line*-side switch to the light(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem isn't what you think it is

Getting neutral down to the load-side switch for the remote (DD00R-DL) used with your dimmer (Leviton DW6HD-1BZ) is easy enough; the white wire in the existing cable can simply be un-redesignated (if it was taped in the first place), then moved over to the neutral junction in the light fixture box.

*However*, this isn't what's stopping you from installing your dimmer.  Your problem is that the DD00R-DL remote needs *line-hot*, a signal wire, and a neutral; however, the incoming hot is only available at the line-side switch box in your setup.  So, you'll have to re-run one of the cables with /4 instead of /3 (or an ENT with THHNs in it) if you want to use this dimmer, or use different hardware that can work with the remote being on the load-side of the setup instead of the line-side.

Comment: gotcha. yes, this makes sense. i don't think i'm really in a position to run all that cable. current plan is to make the 3-way a single-pole, install the dimmer where all the right wires live and abandon the second switch. it's not really that handy, anyway. any problems you can foresee with that fix?

Comment: @david only problem could be if Code requires multi-location control.  what space/room does this light serve?

Comment: it's a bachelor, and it's ridiculous. the switches are maybe 8 feet apart on adjoining walls. if you picture the walls like an L, one switch is at the tip of the short end, and the other switch is just mid-way down the long end. the LIGHT, however is 15 feet from both. so the travelers run from the line box at the short end of the L, ALL THE WAY TO THE LIGHT, then BACK to the load box. so a 30 foot cable run between two switches 8 feet apart. that's why it's maddening to have to deal with this 3-way business, just so i don't have a dead switch above the bed.

Comment: @david -- it's a what, again? (autocomplete seems to have gotten your tongue :/)

Answer (score 3):

It appears pretty clear to me that you can't run the neutral separate from the existing cable, it would be prohibited by NEC 300.3(B) that requires all conductors of a circuit to be contained in the same cable raceway, cable or cord.

We don't know the configuration required for the specific smart switch you are using, at least one model I have used only required one "traveler" between switches, so I was able un-reidentify the white for use as a neutral.

Comment: That was my initial thought about not being able to run a separate neutral too. You can run grounds but not neutrals.  there are smart switches that don't need a neutral.+

Answer (score 1):

If your circuit is wired per the drawing, then the answer is yes you can. The key is the neutral **must** be the same neutral as the line side circuit.

The second part of your question is a little trickier. If you are going to use mechanical three way switches you cannot eliminate one of the carriers since it is necessary to complete the switching sequence. If you use a smart switch which uses electronics for control then you can, but you will have to rearrange the circuitry to get a neutral and a line side circuit to the second box.

There is no standard on electronic controls so we cannot tell you exactly how to connect them up until we know exactly what you are buying. If you are *super green* you may want to seek some local help before making a final purchase.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

### You cannot run a separate, loose neutral wire.

Absolutely not.  The neutral must be in the same cable or conduit as the other wires. So for instance you cannot use 2 cables and just combine em.

It would work if you replaced the /3 in the wall with /4, or if you ran conduit between the two 3-ways.

### However, that won't be a problem with smart switches.

You select a pair of smart switches able to use powerline or wireless signaling.   Then you re-task all the wires as follows:

- Black = always-hot (connects everywhere but the lamp)
- White = neutral (connects everywhere)
- Red = switched-hot from one of the switches to the lamp.  Note the other red segment is unnecessary and should be capped.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit 1:** The simplest solution is.. for the box without the neutral wire, just leave it as a dumb switch and use both traveler wires as traveler wires as per normal 3-way switch wiring. Apparently the wireless switches I bought were able to tell if the light actually was on or off, regardless of the state of the dumb switch. So, with one dumb switch and one smart switch, I can turn the light on or off from the dumb switch, the smart switch, or the app, and everything works perfectly, as expected, and without delays. This is the solution I reverted back to.*

*Side note: I guess the smart switch monitors the voltage and/or amps on the load terminal, and that how it knows the light is on or off? The smart switch contains a little light that indicates when the light is off, so you can see the switch in the dark. If the load light is on and I flip the dumb switch, then the indicator light on the smart switch turns on and my app shows the light is off. So, it knows when the dumb switch flips. Maybe not all smart switches are this smart, but it's probably worth checking yours before you install a smart switch on both ends (even if you have neutral in both boxes!). Maybe replace the dumb switch with a dumb rocker switch if you want it to match the smart switch aesthetics better.*

**Below is the original thread, with additional edits. It might end up being the best solution for some folks.**

I realize this is an old thread, but it's a continuing problem for folks, and there is an alternate solution.

The trick is to remember that you have "smart" switches now.. Also, keep in mind that for this to work, you do need a neutral line in one of your boxes.

1. Redesignate one traveler wire as neutral and connect it to the neutral wire nut. Both boxes now have neutral. ***Edit 2:** @JACK mentioned that it might violate code to redesignate a black, red, blue, etc. wire as neutral. In my case, one of the traveler wires was white, so I used that one for neutral.*
2. Jumper the traveler terminals on both switches. This will ensure the second load switch always has line through the remaining traveler wire, so it stays online. ***Edit 3:** I realized two things as I was wiring and testing. First, there is no need to jumper the switch with line power. Just terminate the traveler wire with the line wire to always send line power to the other switch. Second, jumpering the traveler terminals on the load switch will cause the light to not turn off... So don't do that. Just terminate the one traveler wire onto one traveler terminal and leave the other traveler terminal empty.*
3. Program the switches so that whenever one is turned on or off, the other is also switched correspondingly. The line switch doesn't really need to turn on or off, but you probably want to keep them synchronized, especially if there is a visual indicator on the switch. ***Edit 3:** I encountered a problem that the line switch always thought it was in the on state. When I would hit the switch (manually or through the app), it would turn off, then immediately return to the "on" state (without actually switching). I have no idea why, and I even swapped switches to rule out a faulty switch. That's one reason I went with the simplified solution of using a dumb switch paired with a smart switch.*

With this setup, the line switch doesn't actually do any switching since its traveler terminals are jumpered and always sending line through the single remaining traveler line. The load switch is always doing the switching, either when the user hits the load switch directly or when the user hits the line switch and then the interwebs tell the line switch to flip. The other traveler wire has been redesignated to get neutral to the box that doesn't have it. ***Edit 4:** There is no Edit 4.*

Disclaimer:
I am a mechanical engineer. Hopefully an electrician or EE can comment and verify that this doesn't violate code. :D

Comment: Best answer I've seen. Unfortunately my own problem children are simple switch loops, not three-way, which means that to smartify them I either need to pull new wire or put the smarts in the fixture rather than at the switch (and leave the existing switch turned on or bypass it.) Grump. Older construction, made sense when they built it but...

Comment: I don't think code allows you to re purpose a black, red,blue,etc. to a neutral (white or gray) wire. You can tape or mark a white wire and use it as a hot but not tape a black or other color wire and use it as a neutral in normal residential wiring.

Comment: @JACK Thanks for the tip. In my case one of the traveler wires was actually white, and that's the one that I had redesignated as neutral.

Comment: You lucked out.  :-)

Comment: Haha, yeah. But I ended up reverting to the simplified solution which I just updated in the post. Simpler, easier, cheaper, and I think completely noncontroversial! :D

Comment: @keshlam sorry to hear it. Best of luck with your upgrades!